# Software to determine which VM needs more resources

Tags: linux, monitoring, virtualization, performance-analysis

I have a physical server which runs 8 virtual machines with virt-manager and kvm.

Since one VM is not needed anymore, I want to give the remaining hosts more resources.

I need a tool which helps me to decide:

> Which VM does need more resources?

With "resources" I mean:

- Number of CPUs
- Available RAM

Disk space is not important; there is enough.

Environment: Linux hypervisor, Linux VMs

**Question**

Which tool can help me to decide which VM needs more resources?

It should be open source. Commandline tools are welcome :-)

Comment: There is [a list of kvm management tools](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools).

Answer (score 2):

**[Virtualization Manager](http://www.solarwinds.com/virtualization-manager.aspx)**

- Gain full control of VMware® and Hyper-V® environments
- Hyper-V® and VMware® Management Dashboards
- Identify and remediate VMware and Hyper-V problems
- Decrease mean time to resolution (MTTR)
- VM capacity planning
- VM sprawl control
- VM right-sizing(Display and change VMs with over- and under-allocated CPU/memory. Display and change CPU due to high Co-stop.)
- Free up over-allocated resources and right-size VMs for optimal performance

Hope this helps!!! Cheers!!

Comment: Does this support kvm?